# Redirecting Extension Output to Debug Console - VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

In my extension, sending things I need to `console.log()` works fine while I'm in debug mode with my extension. This sends output to the Debug Console in VS Code during debug mode.

What method(s) are appropriate for sending output from the extension to the Debug Console when not in debug mode, so that the user with my extension installed can see output I want redirected there?

Comment: Hm... in my experience this just works, even when not in debug mode.

Comment: I'm on version 1.33.1 and node 10.2.0. `console.log()` for me sends the output to the dev tools console once the plugin is installed. Will `debug()` in JS accomplish what I'm after, or do I need to setup a terminal object and direct output to that?

Comment: Oh, dev tools console is what I meant.. Maybe you want to create an output channel (`window.createOutputChannel`) for your extension?

Comment: Cheers as always @Gama11 I'll look into that and post once I find something suitable

Comment: @trebleCode , did you find one?